# What's the word this cryptic message refers to?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Constantly move more than 1850 needles to renew your life!

Comment: Sounds like a task on Animal Crossing...

Comment: A crossword would give the number of letters.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe we are rot13(ercynpvat jbeqf jvgu flabalzf, fb jr zvtug frr fbzrguvat yvxr "nyjnlf tb bire 1850 cbvagf...", naq 1850 cbvagf tbbtyrf cerggl jryy nf n fgnaqneq "fvmr" (V unir ab qbznva xabjyrqtr urer) bs na nezl va Jneunzzre.)

Comment: may be Sewing machine (Brother HC1850 Computerized Sewing and Quilting Machine)

Comment: I'm not quite sure. rot13(Qb lbh zrna NAPUBE FHETVPNY ARRQYR CEBQHPGF?)

Comment: It's quite a different approach. rot13(Nf vg jnf eryngrq gb jbeqf. Fb, V pbairegrq 1850 gb NUR_. Gura fgnegrq gb svyy gur oynpx jvgu nycunorgf naq gevrq gb erneenatr fb nf gb trg n zrnavatshy jbeq eryngrq gb erivir. Jura vg ernpurq NURY. Vg pbhyq or erneenatrq nf UrYn juvpu ner pnaprebhf pryyf naq gurersber qvivqr pbagvahbhfyl naq guhf erarj gurve yvirf.)

Comment: Fbeel, V nz BC ohg jura cbfgvat guvf, abg erzrzorevat guvf ybtva qrgnvyf, fb pnzr hc jvgu na vzzrqvngr thrfg cbfgvat, ohg gurernsgre V ernyvmrq V pnaabg npprff onpx gbagur thrfg hfre  Gb gur cbvag: vapbeerpg. V sryg fbzrguvat qvssrerag jura ernqvat lbhe fbyhgvba gb gur ebcr chmmyr..juvpu jnf n Onat!! Abj guvf vf qvffncbvagvat fb sne, lbh ner abg gur bar, fbeel.
(Be ner lbh?:))

Comment: @FIreCase Any Hints would be appreciated. Because the question isn't much specific, it can have multiple answers.

Comment: @S K Ok. Then I will come up with a hint soon

Comment: hint under the only answer

Answer (score 1):

The word could be

> DRIVING

Because

> My first thought when seeing "needles" was some sort of gauge, like for RPM's 
>  Since you need to "move more than 1850", I thought of engine idol speed (1850 is pretty high though)
>  So, you need to move faster than idol speed in order to exist. 
>  So, therefore you won't be sitting idling. You will be driving. 
>  I could be off quite a bit though. By definition, I guess you could even be the automobile itself.

Comment: Fbeel, V nz BC ohg jura cbfgvat guvf, abg erzrzorevat guvf ybtva qrgnvyf, fb pnzr hc jvgu na vzzrqvngr thrfg cbfgvat, ohg gurernsgre V ernyvmrq V pnaabg npprff onpx gbagur thrfg hfre  Gb gur cbvag: vapbeerpg.

Comment: Gunaxf. Nyfb, V ubcr lbh pna trg onpx va gurer jura fbzrbar qbrf pbzr hc jvgu gur pbeerpg nafjre.

Comment: hint: Gd wms aypcdsjjw ylyjwqc wmsp npmnmqcb ylqucp yr rfc qryec wms dglb gr miyw clmsef, zsr zcdmpc bcckgle gr rfc zcqr, gr'q y uyw rm  afcai gd wms amsjb fytc ylqucpcb qmkcrfgle zcrrcp, lmr qspnpgqglejw

Comment: Your hint is in like rot24(). You can leave it though. I got it. Not the real answer but the message.

Comment: Oh. Varietas delectat :) Ok, then I leave it. Thanks.